# How to read numeric/decimal/money columns from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++, odbc

I try to read numeric/decimal/money columns from SQL Server via ODBC in the following manner:

```
SQL_NUMERIC_STRUCT decimal;
SQLGetData(hSqlStmt, iCol, SQL_C_NUMERIC, &decimal, sizeof(decimal), &indicator);
```

All these types are returned as SQL_NUMERIC_STRUCT structure, and I specify the SQL_C_NUMERIC type to SQLGetData() API.

In the database, column is defined as `decimal(18, 4)` for example, or `money`. But the problem is that the returned data has `decimal.precision` always set to 38 (max possible value) and `decimal.scale` always set to zero. So if the actual stored number is **12.65**, the returned value in SQL_NUMERIC_STRUCT structure is equal to **12**. So the fractional part is simply discarded, for a very strange reason.

What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222831) explains the problem. The solution is so cumbersome, that I decided to avoid using `SQL_NUMERIC_STRUCT` altogether, influenced by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258457/what-datatype-should-i-bind-as-query-parameter-to-use-with-number15-column-in). Now I specify `SQL_C_WCHAR` (`SQL_C_CHAR` would do as well) and read the numeric/decimal/money columns as text strings directly. Looks like the driver does the conversion.